# ionic 3 / node.js - Self signed certificate in certificate chain (how to disable strict-ssl?)

Tags: node.js, ssl, ionic-framework

I cannot create a ionic project with `ionic start` because of following error:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
```

on cmd: `ionic start myApp tabs`

Because our proxy sends a self-signed signature for all sites. (FortiGate of FortiNet)

In npm I set `strict-ssl` to `false` and works fine. But ionic loads the content over a node application, right?

How to setup node to ignore self signed certificates for all node applications or how to disable it for ionic?

`ionic info`

```
   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

System:

    Node : v8.9.1
    npm  : 5.5.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Comment: NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 solved my problem. Set it as global system variable or declare it by `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` before running ionic start.

Comment: Do you use a specific system. I tried on macbook and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved my problem using:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` comes at a great risk to the security of your application. I would recommend avoiding this "work around" for production software.
[I recommend reading this before disabling.](http://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5258)

I'm still trying to fix my own issue and will update if I come up with a safer solution.

Comment: Hi my issue was related to OAuth2 and Google or Facebook login requests failing. This was due to an issues with the public and secret keys I was using at the time.

Sorry I can't be anymore helpful. It's been quite a while and my memory dumps frequently!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by disabling my antivirus.