# IONIC error with NPM (deprecated warning)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

in my old ionic version i was able to run and install ionic properly.
but while creating a new project in ionic i get this error
please help me out.

```
C:\>ionic start

Every great app needs a name!

Please enter the full name of your app. You can change this at any time. To bypass this prompt next time, supply name,
the first argument to ionic start.

? Project name: sumith

Let's pick the perfect starter template!

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything you need to build your app. To bypass this
prompt next time, supply template, the second argument to ionic start.

? Starter template: blank
√ Preparing directory .\sumith - done!
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

     *   IONIC  DEVAPP   *

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app


    > npm i
    npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance 
    only, flatted is its successor.
    [    ..............] / fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule 
    punycode@2.1.1 checking installable status
```

Comment: You are getting error npm WARN? Is there no Ionic4 project made? No files in folder? Please explain further...

Answer (score -1):

set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 before running ionic start.

Comment: Please, when you answer something, explain what are you doing and why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680191/ionic-3-node-js-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-how-to-disable

Comment: NO problem, add some reference, and plalce some explanation, people who doesn´t search the other answer will be confused by some broad answer